# Take parts of subject matter from email and input them into excel tabl

Tags: vba, excel

Hello below I have included the current vba script for running thru a file containing multiple emails with specific file names that correspond to address changes discussed in the emails. I want to take the text pertaining to the address change from each of these file names and input the new and old address in an excel table. All the emails in this folder fall into 4 categories of how their title is formatted the following are an example of all four:

- "Address Change Circulation - 14 to 12 Queen Street"
- "Address Change Circulation - from 4 to 2 King Street"
- "Address Change Circulation - 40 south Street to 1 main Avenue"
- "Address Change Circulation - from 4 door street to 2 tenth street".

As you can see they all start with the same string "Address change circulation" however I am having trouble with getting a script that can adapt to all these different scenarios. Below I have included the current iteration of the script If anyone has any suggests or improvements that would be very helpful thank you.

```
Dim StrFile As String
'Change this to the directory containing all Address Change Circulation emails
'This will Pull in a list and, to the best of its ability make two columns that hold the data for
'the old and the new address
StrFile = Dir(Range("AddressChangeFolderPath").Value)
Dim Names() As String
Dim StrName
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    CheckVal = InStr(1, StrFile, "Address Change Circulation -", vbTextCompare) + _
        InStr(1, StrFile, "Address Change Circulation from ", vbTextCompare)
    If CheckVal <> 1 Then   'if the email does not fit the standard, just place it in the cell and
                            'move on to the next entry
        Selection.Value = StrFile
        Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'highlight the cell
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Else
        StrName = Right(StrFile, Len(StrFile) - 29) 'trim to the correct size - probably not the
                                                    'best way to do this but it works
        If Left(StrName, 4) = "from" Then
            StrName = Right(StrName, Len(StrName) - 5)
        ElseIf Left(StrName, 2) = "om" Then
 StrName = Right(StrName, Len(StrName) - 3)
        End If
        StrName = Left(StrName, Len(StrName) - 4)
        Changes = Split(StrName, " and ")
        For Each Change In Changes
            Names = Split(Change, " to ")

            If Len(Names(0)) < 5 Then
                Selection.Value = Names(0) & Right(Names(1), Len(Names(1)) - Len(Names(0)))
            Else
                Selection.Value = Names(0)
            End If
            If UBound(Names) >= 1 Then 'this is a zero indexed array, checking greater than or
                                       'equal to 1 will check if there are two or more entries
                Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value = Names(1) ' in the event that there is no " to " in
                                                'the file name and it hasn't been handeled already
            End If
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select 'select the next cell to accept the next entry
        Next
    End If

loop
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? It's difficult to answer because I can't tell what you're trying to ask. Does the script currently work? What problems are you facing?

Comment: Yes the script currently works for the first two cases I listed but not the last two cases. The problem I am facing is being able to account for the last two cases (the script currently accounts for the other two).  Another thing which is more of a question than a problem is that I am wondering if there are any better methods or functions for parsing data from file names? This current method is mostly a large number of if statements enclosed in a while loop. If there was another way that didn't rely on the file name being uniform and using right() or left funtion I would be open to using that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples, this is probably a reasonable approach.
It's easier to manage if you split your parsing out into a separate method.

Just parsing texts from a range on a worksheet:

```
Sub Process()
    Dim c As Range, op As String, np As String

    For Each c In Range("A1:A6").Cells
        ParseAddresses c.Value, op, np '<< passing np/op by reference...
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = op
        c.Offset(0, 2).Value = np
    Next c

End Sub

'Parse two addresses from "t" into "op" and "np"
Sub ParseAddresses(ByVal t, ByRef op As String, ByRef np As String)
    Dim arr

    op = "": np = ""
    t = Trim(t)
    If t Like "Address Change Circulation -*to*" Then
        t = Replace(t, "Address Change Circulation -", "")
        t = Replace(t, "from", "")
        arr = Split(t, "to")
        op = Trim(arr(0))
        np = Trim(arr(1))
        ' "from" part is just a number: replace number in "to" part
        If IsNumeric(op) Then
            arr = Split(np, " ")
            arr(0) = op
            op = Join(arr, " ")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```